# Is it possible to make a webservice per user?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a webservice (.asmx) and I want it to retain a value on a per-user basis. Is this possible?

ie (pseudo-code)

```
MyWebservice
{

object perUserVariable = something;

[WebMethod]
public void myMethod()
{
    if (something == null)
    {
      something = doBigExpensivedatabaseCall();
    }
    return something;
}

}
```

Comment: it goes against the normal stateless design of web services to do so....

Comment: Contrary to the common statement the web is stateless, the web is actually very stateful otherwise databases, session, cache etc all would have no reason to exist in regards to web applications.

Comment: One problem is that you are writing C# `camelCased` instead of `PascalCased`!  *(just kidding)*

Comment: The most common C# naming conventions use both camelCase and PascalCase, while being overly simple, generally any global thing ends up PascalCased whereas local things are camelCase.

Comment: I swear - I don't put pseudo code I get told off for having bad variable names and things that don't match... I put pseudocode and I still get grief!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ASP.NET's session mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).
Change your `WebMethod` attribute, so that it will look like that:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

This is normally achieved by cookies, or by sending the session id in the query string (both ways are completely handled by ASP.NET). The former is the default, to achieve the latter, just set `cookieless="true"` in your config.web file.

Comment: A method cannot contain global variables so I'm not sure how that would work

Comment: @SLC - Why do you think a method can't use global variables?

Comment: It can use them but it can't contain them... the perUserVariable in my post is not in the method, it's in the class - so I need to enable session on that surely

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to pass in some kind of user identifier to specify who the user is, do your operation and instead of storing it in something you will to use a durable or semi-durable store such as Cache or Session. Then look that value up from the Cache or Session instead of a local member.

Also fwiw the way you have that configured the fact something isn't static means it would be null on every single request because it would be newly initialized. Making it static however would then server the individual instance of something to each and every request there after.

This is why you need to use a store that can differentiate on the user such as Cache[userid+"something"] or the Session["something"] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your choices seem to be using some type of caching system like session or [memcache](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com).

Session will require a session id passed as a cookie to the requests.  Other caching providers could probably key off of a post value like the userid.